# Will an anti-neutron annihilate a regular neutron even though they have no charge

Tags: antimatter, neutrons

Since neutrons have no electric charge will an anti-neutron annihilate when it comes into contact with a regular neutron as protons and anti-protons do? if so what causes it to annihilate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neutron and antineutron have also an internal structure formed by quarks.
A neutron is composed by 2 down quarks, each with a charge -1/3, and one up quark with a charge of 2/3.  This gives a total charge of 0.
Antineutron are different, they have 2 anti-down quarks (each with a charge of 1/3) and one antiup quark (-2/3) of charge.
So, even though they have a total charge of zero they still are antiparticles.  In a simplified view, it's like if they have a mirrored internal structure.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will. Annihilation is a form of interaction which only happens between a particle and its anti-particle. You can sort of imagine it even though its not completely true I think, as destructive interference of the same particle field. Its independent of charge.